# Session hijack: Login as B user who supposed to have less privileges, using A user session id gets all the access as Admin

Tags: security, web-applications

Our web app is Java app and functionality goes like below:

1. Chrome browser: The user A logged in with the role "admin" having all the access> Copy session id
2. Firefox browser: User B logged in as role "LimitedUser" on the same web portal with less access.
3. Paste the session id which was copied from Chrome browser in Firefox browser> The user is treated as Admin now.

Is this an issue really? Since our cookies are already set flags - https, secure and site is hosted with https so less chances of leaking session id.

Can we report this as security issue. please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After authentication with username and password I guess, the user is issued a session id. From then on, the session id is used transparently for the user to authenticate further requests, so they don't have to type username and password all the time. Their username and password is exchanged for a temporary session id if you like, which for the duration of the session is equivalent to their credentials. This means losing the session id to an attcker is very similar to losing the username and password (with some notable differences, like for example it's timebound).

So acknowledging this, you can see that as the web application really has nothing else to authenticate the user in subsequent requests other than the session id, whoever has the session id will be authenticated as the user that it belongs to (sidenote: you can apply some further controls, like for example binding the session to a client IP address and so on, but these will have implications on UX etc.)

So this is not a vulnerability, it's just how it works, and this is exactly why you should implement proper session security, by protecting the cookie that holds the session id from attacks like eavesdropping (by using https, and applying the `secure` flag to the cookie), and xss (by applying the `httpOnly` flag), generating secure enough session ids, preventing session fixation and so on.

The easiest to achieve this is to use your framework's built in facilities, which will probably get it right.